# Unable to set step size in ign gazebo

Tags: gazebo

I'm trying to run a simulation in gazebo fortress for reinforcement learning. I can't set the step size. My sdf file looks like this:

```
<sdf version="1.5">
<world name="rl_world">
    <include>
        <uri>/path/to/terrain.sdf</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>/path/to/robot.urdf</uri>
    </include>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo6-contact-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Contact" />
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo6-physics-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics">
        <max_step_size>0.01</max_step_size>
        <real_time_update_rate>100</real_time_update_rate>
        <real_time_factor>-1</real_time_factor>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo6-scene-broadcaster-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster" />
</world>
```

But in gazebo I see this:

[image: screenshot of gazebo GUI with step size set to 0.001]

I'm also unable to change those values - they immediately revert to the defaults. I'm not seeing any error messages when I run gazebo with "-v 4".

It also uses that step size (0.001) when I run gazebo via the c++ api as part of my RL algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the `max_step_size`, `real_time_update_rate` and `real_time_factor` parameters to the Physics system's XML `<plugin/>` block, but these parameters should be added to a `<physics/>` XML block as a child of the `<world/>` element. See one of the example worlds from `gz-sim` for reference:

https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/examples/worlds/empty.sdf#L64-L67